# Chart control assign Y-values to specific X-values

Tags: c#, sql, asp-classic, charts

I got a homepage with a chart that needs to display the last five dates on the X-values.  The Y-values need to display the hours registered over the last five days on the date it was registered. For example, last five days:

```
31-01-2014
01-02-2014
02-02-2014
03-02-2014
04-02-2014
```

It needs to show the hours registered if there were any registrations on those dates.

The sql query selects the date and hours registered between 4 days ago and today. The X-values are now given by an IEnumerable that I created that contains a list with the last 5 days. I pasted that as the X-value member in DatabindXY. I pasted the results of the hours as the y-values. The problem is, that it assigns the y-values to the incorrect days. I understand why it's not working, because I don't have any logic of telling the chart to assign the y-values to the correct date. the dates results from the query isn't being used anywhere to assign the correct values. So If I have done a registration (which occurs on a different page) on the 2nd of February, the chart assigns the registration to the first date that occurs in the x-value. In this case 31-01-2014.

How do I correctly assign the Y-values to the correct dates? 
I haven't been programming for that long and I haven't done anything with a chart control before as well. Do I need to use the Datamanipulator function ? Or code the logic in the databound of the chart? I have searched the web and couldn't figure it out.

Sorry if the problem is unclear. English isn't my native language:).

The code that I have so far in the page load is:

```
List<object> lijst = new List<object>();
lijst.Add(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-4));
lijst.Add(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-3));
lijst.Add(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-2));
lijst.Add(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1));
lijst.Add(DateTime.Now.Date);

IEnumerable<object> data = lijst;
string begin = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
string eind = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

SqlCommand cmdChart = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Minuten) / 60 as Minuten, Datum FROM Uren WHERE         Datum BETWEEN @Begin AND @Eind AND WerknemerID = @WerknemerID  GROUP BY Datum ORDER BY Datum ", con);
cmdChart.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WerknemerID", Session["werknemer"]);
cmdChart.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Begin", begin);
cmdChart.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eind", eind);
con.Open();

Chart1.DataSource = cmdChart.ExecuteReader();
Chart1.DataBind();
con.Close();
con.Open();
SqlDataReader myRead;
myRead = cmdChart.ExecuteReader();

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Datum";
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Uren geregistreerd";

Chart1.AlternateText = "Laatste 5 dagen geen uren geregistreerd";

Chart1.Series["Testing"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
Chart1.Series["Testing"].Points.DataBindXY(data, "Datum", myRead, "Minuten");

con.Close();
```

Solved:

```
public class ChartPoint
{
    public DateTime x { get; set; }
    public string y { get; set; }
}

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmdChart.ExecuteReader();

        table.Load(dr);
        con.Close();

        List<ChartPoint> ChartPoints = new List<ChartPoint>();
        ChartPoints.Add(new ChartPoint() { x = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-4), y = "0" });
        ChartPoints.Add(new ChartPoint() { x = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-3), y = "0" });
        ChartPoints.Add(new ChartPoint() { x = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-2), y = "0" });
        ChartPoints.Add(new ChartPoint() { x = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1), y = "0" });
        ChartPoints.Add(new ChartPoint() { x = DateTime.Now.Date, y = "0" }); 


        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime Xdate = (DateTime)table.Rows[i]["Datum"];
            string Yminuten = table.Rows[i]["Minuten"].ToString();
            int index = lijst.IndexOf((DateTime)table.Rows[i]["Datum"]);
            ((ChartPoint)ChartPoints[index]).x = Xdate;
            ((ChartPoint)ChartPoints[index]).y = Yminuten;
        }

        Chart1.Series["Testing"].Color = Color.CadetBlue;
        foreach (var item in ChartPoints)
        {
            Chart1.Series["Testing"].Points.AddXY(item.x.ToString(), item.y);
        }
        Chart1.DataBind();
```

Thanks for guiding me on the right path Somnath.

Answer (score 2):

Take the result in datatable "table" and try this following code it will use for you

```
DataTable table= new DataTable();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

table.Load(dr);

for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Xdate= table.Rows[i]["Datum"].ToString();
    Yminuten= table.Rows[i]["Minuten"].ToString();

    Chart1.Series["Testing"].Points.AddXY(Xdate, Yminuten);               
    Chart1.Series["Testing"].Color = Color.Goldenrod;
}    

Chart1.DataBind();
```

I Hope this will work for You

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! This solved one issue, but caused another. The X-values doesn't show the last 5 days. It only shows the last 5 days which contain hours registered. Is it possible to show the last 5 days as default and correctly assign the Y-values to the correct dates?
Example:
No hours registered in the last 5 days except on the 4th of February. The chart shows 1 X-value with the hours as Y. I would like the other 4 days to show as well.

Thanks again.